# Inputs reset after making copy of row

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a copy of a row to add another line of inputs but every time I click the button the value of every input resets.

Here is what I've written so far:

```
<div style="margin-left: 2em;margin-right: 2em;">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
>!                   th`s
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="aditional">
                  <tr id="template">
>!                    inputs and blank td`s
                  </tr>
                  <script>

                    const temp = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML;
                    const adit = document.getElementById("aditional");

                    function add() {
                        adit.innerHTML+='<tr>'+temp+'</tr>';
                        renum();
                    }

                    function renum() {
                        const lp = document.getElementsByClassName("lp"); 
                        for(let i=0;i<lp.length;i++) {
                            lp[i].innerHTML = i+1;
                        }
                    }
                    
                  </script>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="add()">Dodaj</button>
        </div>
```

Ive tried:
`const temp = (document.getElementById("template").innerHTML).toString()`

Comment: `adit.innerHTML+='...'` doesn't "push" an element into the `#aditional` element, leaving everything untouched, it replaces everything inside with an updated value (which just happens to be largely the same) So all your inputs are replaced with their default state. Have a look at [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead of [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). It's even clearly stated on the official documentation there:

> To insert the HTML into the document rather than replace the contents of an element, use the method `insertAdjacentHTML()`.

That said, you can't use `innerHTML` on table rows:

```js
function showValues() {
    const div = document.getElementById('div');
  const divInnerHTML = div.innerHTML;
  
  const tr = document.getElementById('tr');
  const trInnerHTML = tr.innerHTML;
  
  console.log("Div innerHTML: "+divInnerHTML);
  console.log("Tr innerHTML: "+trInnerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<table>
  <tr id="tr">
    <input type="text">
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="showValues()">
Show
</button>
```

As you see, the `div` returns its innerHTML just fine. The table row does not.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the input values from resetting, you should avoid directly manipulating the `innerHTML`, which causes the inputs to lose their values.

```html
<div style="margin-left: 2em; margin-right: 2em;">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- Your table headers -->
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
                <!-- Add more headers as needed -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="additional">
            <tr id="template">
                <!-- Your template row with inputs -->
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <!-- Add more columns with inputs as needed -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>

    <script>
        function addRow() {
            const templateRow = document.getElementById("template");
            const tableBody = document.getElementById("additional");

            // Clone the template row
            const newRow = templateRow.cloneNode(true);
            
            // Clear input values in the cloned row if needed
            const inputs = newRow.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                inputs[i].value = ''; // Reset input values if needed
            }

            // Append the cloned row to the table
            tableBody.appendChild(newRow);
            
            // Recalculate any numbering or other operations needed
            renumerateRows();
        }

        function renumerateRows() {
            const rows = document.getElementById("additional").getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                // Update row numbers or perform other operations as needed
                // For example, if you have a row numbering column (change "lp" to your specific class)
                const rowNumber = i + 1;
                rows[i].querySelector('.lp').innerHTML = rowNumber;
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```